# Roundabout Plugin with 5 images shown

Tags: javascript

Im a beginner in javascript programming and i have a trouble with roundabout plugin http://fredhq.com/

I need to make the plugin only show 5 images when its static. I've tried google it and no success of course. I've read the roundabout's docs but it didnt find anything about number of images shown.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

these are the codes: http://jsfiddle.net/ramon_v/h683A/

`

```
    <ul>
        <li><span>Block 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Block 2</span></li>
        <li><span>Block 3</span></li>
        <li><span>Block 4</span></li>
        <li><span>Block 5</span></li>
        <li><span>Block 4</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
</body>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.roundabout2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul').roundabout({
           btnNext: '#next',
           btnPrev: '#prev',
           duration: 200
        });
    });
</script>`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I put together a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thejohnsmith/h683A/5/) based on your question; it includes five images.

The javaScript will stay the same:

```
$('ul').roundabout({
  btnNext: '#next',
  btnPrev: '#prev',
  duration: 200
});
```

**The steps I took to get it working:**

1. Since roundabout is a jQuery plugin make sure to load it in the JsFiddle Frameworks section (you had mootools loading which might cause conflicts)
2. JsFiddle loads all of the html wrappers for you, so you don't have to write in the html, head or body in here.
3. Load roundabout as an external resource in the JsFiddle External Resources section. You need to find a static web link to the actual .js file. In this case there is one on github ([Link](https://raw.github.com/fredhq/roundabout/master/jquery.roundabout.min.js))
4. The example you were working with only requires a few css rules so I deleted all the rest.

I hope this answers any questions you had.

Happy coding!